# How to customise Flexibility 5 theme for ModX?

Tags: modx, flexibility

Hello i tried to add the link to custom.css in "assets/components/flexibility5/chunks/flex5.header.html"

But changes are not saved even when the file is set as static - even not the setting for static file. The only way to make a change is over FTP but it is still not showing when in the front end.
What to do?

Comment: Have you tried editing the chunk from within the MODX manager? That should update the file (if it is set to static, but it might not be) and also clear the cache to make sure it shows up on the site.

Comment: @MarkHamstra Mod Security was preventing changes so I had to turn it off temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod Security prevents changes so it has to be turned off temporarily.